# How to poll only the last modified file from folder using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

In my Spring based application I want to poll folder and get only the file with closest last modified date (the recent one) using Camel. The files in folder should be not deleted by Camel.

I've tried to start a route with next options:

```
from("file:C:/test?noop=true&sortBy=reverse:file:modified&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&maxMessagesPerPoll=1)
  .routeId("MainRoute")
  .bean(FileProcessor.class);
}
```

With such configuration Camel takes the recent file, process it and after that start to work with the next file.

But in my scenario it should take only the last file: if no files were added it must take the same file every time. If the recent file will be deleted it must find another recent file.

How can it be achieved in Camel?

Comment: what if your folder is empty? how will it find recent file?

Comment: @BSangappa, it is assumed that the folder will not be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to find a simple solution. According to docs:

> If noop=true, Camel will set idempotent=true as well, to avoid consuming the same files over and over again.

So, in order to achieve the desired behavior we have to set `idempotent` parameter back to `false`. With such setup Camel will not exclude any files from checks:

```
from("file:C:/test?noop=true&idempotent=false&sortBy=reverse:file:modified&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&maxMessagesPerPoll=1)
  .routeId("MainRoute")
  .bean(FileProcessor.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your own *file filter* implementation that has this logic, where you keep state per folder which was the last file you accepted there. Then the filter can return true or false whether to pickup a file.

In that logic you can use the Java file API to list all the files to find if there is another file with a newer timestamp, etc.

Comment: according to doc: "Pluggable filter as a org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter class. Will skip files if filter returns false in its accept() method." So it can filter files in directory.  How can I access this directory? Only to find parent of the file? in this case I have to iterate over all files, call parent and perform checks. I think it will be not so fast as it could be.